Vite with Vuejs hot reload module reload full page instead of update
When I save a javascript file in my vue 3 project (api composition).
This reloads the entire page instead of just updating the data.

I checked that the javascript files have exactly the same name during imports
I tested with export default instead of export const in my js files
I checked that there is no circular import in my project
I checked with usePolling: true

It works perfectly with vue files but javascript files, impossible
I'm running out of solutions
Thanks for your help !

Tbh, that's normal behavior in my opinion. Import .js files usually warrant a full page reload when changed. They often export stuff or other stuff depends on them, so new changes are handled by reloading.
